# Koala like doesn´t work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I am currently develop a facebook application.
I create actions and objects with opengraph and i can post new objects in my application with the koala methods. This work all certainly.

Now i want to post a like to a specified object

in my rails console i try to use something like this:

`user = User.find("id")`

`user.facebook.get_connection("me", "my_namespace:like", object: "myobjecturl")`

The facebook method defines the koala api object 
`Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)`

but i got a exception

`Koala::Facebook::APIError: OAuthException: Unknown path components: /my_namespace:like`

Answer (score 2):

To be more explicit, here's the precise code for Koala:

```
user.facebook.put_connections("me", "og.likes", object: "myobjecturl")
```

Facebook won't let you define a custom like action for your app, so you have to use "og.likes" without a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the [build-in Open Graph like action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/) here – that has to be published against `/userid/og.likes` (and *not* `/userid/my_namespace:like` as you’re trying to do).